# Drupal: Retrieving database

Tags: database, module, block

I'm fairly new to Drupal, and I need your help on this issue:

I have built a module on Drupal 7 which makes a database query to extract the name and the email of all users. The code is this:

```
<?php

/**
 *
 */

function myexample_block_info() {
  $blocks['myblock'] = array(
   'info' => t('My Custom Modue'),
   );

  return $blocks;
}

function myexample_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  $results = db_select('users','a')
    ->fields('a', array('name', 'mail'))
    ->execute();

    $header = array(t('NAME'), t('MAIL'));
    $rows = array();

    foreach ($results as $node) {
     $rows[] = array(
       $node->name,
       $node->mail,

    );
    }

$block['content'] = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));

  return $block;

}
```

I put the block into "Side-bar first"-Bartik theme. The code works and it retrieves what I want. But the problem with the display. I'm getting the results repeated 3 times:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCSUM.png)

Why am I getting the results repeated three times. I cant seem to find anything wrong with the code. Could anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve ? If you are just trying to extract data from the DB this is not the way to go. You should extract data via mysql client directly.